# How do you parse pdf files from a raw dataset in Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks, foundry-python-transform, palantir-foundry-api

I have a raw dataset which comprises of multiple PDF files. I want to be able to get a Foundry Dataset which has the text for each of these pdfs in one column, and the name of the document in the other.

[image]

Let's assume xyz.pdf has text asdf
Let's assume yyz has text zxcv
I want a dataset which has:

```
doc_name | text |
-----------------
xyz.pdf  | asdf |
yyz.pdf  | zxcv |
```

My approach is to open the file, and send to a library which does document parsing (tika, pdfplumber, docquery).  When I run something like this:

```
with source.filesystem().open('xyz.pdf','rb') as f:
    pdf = pdfplumber.open(f)
    print(pdf)
```

I get the error:

```
  File "/tmp/conda-xyz/real/environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/psparser.py", line 220, in seek
    self.fp.seek(pos)
io.UnsupportedOperation: File or stream is not seekable.
```

If I just try and open the file directly, I get:

```
pdf = pdfplumber.open('xyz.pdf')
```

I get the error:

```
  File "/tmp/conda-xyz/real/environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfplumber/pdf.py", line 71, in open
    stream = open(path_or_fp, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xyz.pdf'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that `filesystem.open` for the Foundry File System does not return same type of object as standard 'open'. To create a seekable I/O buffer, we need to copy the contents to a local file then use Python's open (or a library which uses Python's open).

A code snippet with just the opening of the file is:

```
with source.filesystem().open(file_path,'rb') as f:
     with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
          shutil.copyfileobj(f, tmp)
          tmp.flush()
          # you can now use tmp like you would with just the file, ie
          pdf = pdfplumber.open(tmp)
```

Here is a full solution:

```
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 from transforms.api import transform, transform_df, Input, Output
 import pandas as pd
 import pdfplumber
 import tempfile
 import shutil

@transform(
    output=Output("/path/to/pdf_text_parsed"),
    source=Input("/path/to/pdf_raw_files")
)
    list_file = list(source.filesystem().ls())
    
    #since using a loop, keep track of values in empty lists
    doc_texts = []
    doc_names = []

    for file_ in list_file:
        file_path = file_.path
        
        with source.filesystem().open(file_path,'rb') as f:
                doc_text = []
                doc_names.append(file_path)
                with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(f, tmp)
                    tmp.flush()
                    pdf = pdfplumber.open(tmp)
                    #process page by page
                    for page in pdf.pages:
                        text = page.extract_text()
                        doc_text.append(text)
                    doc_texts.append(doc_text)

    d = {'doc_name':doc_names,'doc_text':doc_texts}

    result_pd = pd.DataFrame(d)
    result =  ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(result_pd)
    output.write_dataframe(result)
```

The end result is a dataset in Foundry called pdf_text_parsed:

```
doc_name | doc_text |
---------------------
xyz.pdf  | asdf     |
yyz.pdf  | zxcv     |
```